# How can I get current user id in django views.py? (CBV)

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I want to get current user id in views.py (CBV) and pass it to forms.py in order to filter my model objects before submitting my form in template.
I didn't find any good answer.

Comment: What's wrong with `request.user`? If you want a better answer, you need to show some code. (And don't use "wanna", it is not a word.)

Comment: request does not work in cbv views and forms.py.
`name 'request' is not defined`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try: 
views.py

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(CoolView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'user': self.request.user})
        return kwargs
```

forms.py

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
    super(CoolForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if user:
        ….
```